# Apache Too many Connections Open which causes slow loading of site

Tags: apache

when start my apache server it opens to many connections which causes slow loading of site then  stop apache and then start again then issue resolved but after some time again to many apache connection open any solution for this

Comment: not enough information to answer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have to find out what these connections are, why they are created and how to remove them, or close them faster.